# Get latest record for each TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, select, db2, sql-timestamp

I have this query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, 
       TIMESTAMP_OFFER, 
       TIMESTAMP_TRACK, 
       STATUS_ACPT 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  TIMESTAMP IN 
(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP 
    FROM   TABLE2 
    WHERE  STATUS = '1' 
    AND    TIMESTAMP_PROCESSED BETWEEN 
            '2017-01-07-00.00.00.000000' 
        AND '2017-01-17-00.00.00.000000'
)
```

And result:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | TIMESTAMP                  | TIMESTAMP_OFFER               | TIMESTAMP_TRACK            | STATUS_ACPT |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-09 11:26:29.434254  | 2017-01-25 14:36:23.587199    | 2017-01-25 14:36:23.587199 | P           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-09 11:26:29.434254  | 2017-02-01 16:05:02.221179    | 2017-02-01 16:05:02.221179 | P           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-09 11:26:29.434254  | 2017-02-01 16:05:02.221179    | 2017-07-13 10:59:20.342584 | E           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-11 15:09:51.935322  | 2017-02-11 12:00:50.410959    | 2017-02-11 12:00:50.410959 | P           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-11 15:09:51.935322  | 2017-02-11 12:00:50.410959    | 2017-02-11 12:10:50.410959 | A           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need latest record for each TIMESTAMP, I should get this:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | TIMESTAMP                  | TIMESTAMP_OFFER               | TIMESTAMP_TRACK            | STATUS_ACPT |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-09 11:26:29.434254  | 2017-02-01 16:05:02.221179    | 2017-07-13 10:59:20.342584 | E           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |2017-01-11 15:09:51.935322  | 2017-02-11 12:00:50.410959    | 2017-02-11 12:10:50.410959 | A           |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I get it?

As you can see, TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP_OFFER can have duplicate values but TIMESTAMP_TRACK is unique.

Comment: You have to give us more details! It is not clear why you expect the resultset shown as other rows with duplicate timestamps would qualify as well - so what is the complete business requiremet.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher requirement is to get result for given TIMESTAMP based on latest TIMESTAMP_OFFER and TIMESTAMP_TRACK. Because TIMESTAMP_TRACK is unique, I should be able to get only one(latest) record.

Comment: 1) Classic example of a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.  2) [Don't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - you're selecting the first instant of 1/17, which is almost certainly not what you want (yes, the post is written for SQL Server, but the reasoning is universal - remember, too that some DB2 versions allow you to specify fractional seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table1 is the result table shown above you could solve it with this query:

```
with temp as (
select timestamp, timestamp_offer, timestamp_track, status_acpt,
       row_number() over (order by timestamp desc) as rownum_timestamp,
       row_number() over (order by timestamp_offer desc) as rownum_timestamp_offer
  from table1)
  select timestamp, timestamp_offer, timestamp_track
    from temp
   where rownum_timestamp = 1 or rownum_timestamp_offer = 1
```

The Common Table Expression is used to add the rownumbers - one for each timestamp column you need the maximum from and in the main SQL statement only the rows with rownumber = 1 are retrieved. Note the sort order - it is descending so rownumber 1 is the maximum timestamp.